# jquery dialog loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Let's say i've a div with several html info and structures and when i convert it to a dialog with `jquery $("#infodata).dialog(...);` it takes several seconds to be showed.

So, it's there a way or method that can be implemented to know when **jquery** finished rendering the dialog?

P.D : there's no ajax request, the html is still there but with display:none.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain triggering an event on to the end of it, then you get

`$("#infodata).dialog(...).closest('body').trigger('dialogueLoaded');`

`$('body').on('dialogueLoaded', function() { doOtherStuff() });`

Comment: thanks for your answer but i wanted to show a preloading message when the dialog is rendering... i guess in your example that the trigger is when it finishes, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to show a preloading message, you can do:
`showLoading();`
`$("#infodata).dialog(...).closest('body').trigger('dialogueLoaded');`
`$('body').on('dialogueLoaded', function() { hideLoading(); doOtherStuff(); });`

Where showLoading shows your loading message however you want.